# PhpMyAdmin shows warning: PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.24

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade, mysql, phpmyadmin

Installed Mysql on Ubuntu 12.04 Server via

> apt-get install mysql-server

from default sources.list. Than uploaded new Phpmyadmin version shows warning:

> Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server
>   version 5.5.24. This may cause unpredictable behavior.

How I can install new Mysql 5.5 version? Could you please advice?

Cheers

Comment: try re-installing `php5-mysql` by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-mysql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, the PHP team need to launch an update to the `libmysql` file, this way, you can use a newer version of the Database.

If you want to update the PHP installation, just update the file `libmysql` to the version you want *(if there is any available yet)*.

Try executing these commands:

```bsh
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-mysql
apt-get install php5-mysqli
```

[Here is the official installation guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/apis-php-mysqli.setup.html).